# How to pass structure field name to function?

Tags: c, struct

I have many similar function calls dealing with one structure, but each call is using different field of structure.

Example:

```
 typedef struct {
     int i1;
     int i2;
     int i3;
    } S;
```

functions to get structure fields (it would be better to avoid them):

```
int getFieldI1 (S *s){ return s->i1; }

int getFieldI2 (S *s){ return s->i2; }

int getFieldI3 (S *s){ return s->i3; }
```

function i have to call many times:

```
void doJob (int (*get_field_func)(S *)){
 //some code
 S s;
 int v = get_field_func(&s);
 //some code 
}
```

i call doJob() this way:

```
doJob(&getFieldI1);
doJob(&getFieldI2);
doJob(&getFieldI3);
```

i would like to do like this:

```
doJob(i1);
doJob(i2);
doJob(i3);
```

is it possible in C?

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this with a *macro*, but not a *function*.

Comment: A you sure with this: `int getFieldI2 (S *s){ return s->i1; }

int getFieldI3 (S *s){ return s->i1; }` or are those two `i1` a typo?

Comment: Hiding something, yet wanting to reference it seems conflicting. Decide what you want to expose, to determine the field. Maybe int index of field? Maybe enum? Maybe string id? Answer depends on what the caller is allowed to know.

Comment: Is that really the structure you are using, or is that just a contrived example?  If it is  your real code, then an array of integers would be simpler than a structure.

Comment: @hyde  Indeed.  `int getFieldI2 (S *s){ return s->i2; }` is pointless.  If you know you want field `i2` **just write `s->i2` and be done**.  Don't be "clever" when writing code.  That just makes it harder to understand.

Comment: Note: C calls `i1, i2, i3` as _members_ of the `struct`, not _fields_.  C does use _field_ as in `bit-fields`.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica: first i checked this moment in K&R(RUS) - they say members, elements or fields; after your note i checked in K&R(ENG) - they say just members. Decided to delete K&R(RUS).

Comment: In real application i used function pointers, but now after some answers, i think it would be better to use any macro, maybe with offsetof(). It is better to use function pointers when they may change at runtime, but when you need something constant - use macro.

Answer (score 2):

## option 1 - offsets

You can use memory offsets.

```
void doJob (int offset){
    //some code
    S s;
    int v = *(&s+offset*sizeof(int));
    //some code
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
doJob(0);//i1
doJob(1);//i2
doJob(2);//i3
```

As pointed out in the comments, the offsets are unsafe. You can create a check for this:

```
if(offset>2||offset<0){
    //some kind of error
}
```

Also, this can only be used if the structure only contains integers(or elements of the same type, you would need to adjust it)(see comments).

If there are elements before s1, s2 and s3, you'll need to add the size of the elements(as padding, just add it);

## option 2 - constants

Another option (that hasn't the mentioned problems) is to define constants/macros:

You'll just define them like this:

```
#define I1 &getFieldI1
#define I2 &getFieldI2
#define I3 &getFieldI3
```

and just call it using:

```
doJob(I1);
doJob(I2);
doJob(I3);
```

Comment: That is an unsafe solution and would only work at all if the structure is as described in the question and that is not simply an example.  Moreover, if that is a solution, then an array of integers would be better that a structure.

Comment: Offset? Is it safe?

Comment: @Nicholas: Only is no padding has been added - which is only "likely" when the members are `int`, but not guaranteed.  Moreover it only works when all members are of the same type.

Comment: Thanks. I've added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a pointer to the field:

```
void doJob( int* fieldPointer )
{
    assert( fieldPointer != NULL );

    // Get the field value:
    int v = *fieldPointer;

    // Do something with the field value:
    v += 10;

    // Save the updated value back to the field:
    *fieldPointer = v;
}
```

Usage:

```
S structInstance = ...

doJob( &structInstance.i1 );
doJob( &structInstance.i2 );
doJob( &structInstance.i3 );
```

Comment: Structure is defined inside doJob(), so i can not use pointer.

Comment: Seems he wants to do some abstraction hiding, so this is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass structure field name to function?

In general, you cannot. A typical library coded in C does not show fields of internal `struct` to outside. In other words, a field name is only known to the compiler, and relevant to the current [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), and makes no sense at runtime.

Consider the following [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approach: write a metaprogram (in C or in some scripting language like [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), [Python](https://python.org/), etc...) generating your C code, and set up your build accordingly. That might mean to edit your [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), or configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool.

This is usual practice since the previous century. Look into [SWIG](http://swig.org/) or [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) as a famous example.

You might perhaps use [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) tricks, e.g. [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Answer (score 0):

I failed to guess right types for i1/i2/i3, sorry. So I use auto keyword from c++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
     int i1;
     int i2;
     int i3;
    } S;

int getFieldI1 (S *s){ return s->i1; }
int getFieldI2 (S *s){ return s->i2; }
int getFieldI3 (S *s){ return s->i3; }

void doJob (int (*get_field_func)(S *)){
 //some code
 S s = {1,2,3};
 //S s;
  int v = get_field_func(&s);
 //some code
 printf("got: %d\n", v);
}

int main() {
  S s = {1,2,3};
  auto i1 = getFieldI1;
  auto i2 = getFieldI2;
  auto i3 = getFieldI3;

  doJob(i1);
  doJob(i2);
  doJob(i3);
}
```

Then

```
g++ 59503102.cxx -o 59503102 && ./59503102
```

as expected produces

```
got: 1
got: 2
got: 3
```

plain c version

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
     int i1;
     int i2;
     int i3;
    } S;

int getFieldI1 (S *s){ return s->i1; }
int getFieldI2 (S *s){ return s->i2; }
int getFieldI3 (S *s){ return s->i3; }

void doJob (int (*get_field_func)(S *)){
 //some code
 S s = {1,2,3};
 //S s;
  int v = get_field_func(&s);
 //some code
 printf("got: %d\n", v);
}

int main() {
  S s = {1,2,3};
  int (*i1)(S *) = getFieldI1;
  int (*i2)(S *) = getFieldI2;
  int (*i3)(S *) = getFieldI3;

  doJob(i1);
  doJob(i2);
  doJob(i3);
}
```

Comment: The question is about C, not C++

Comment: I noticed :)
Still I believe "int (*i1)(S *) = getFieldI1;" is uglier than "auto i1 = getFieldI1;"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C doesn't allow exactly what you need. But you can achieve a partial win with some code changes.

I have one and half solutions. For the first I propose a (**simplified!**) implementation, for the second I provide just an hint. Please, check if they can be acceptable for you.

Your example structure:

```
typedef struct {
     int i1;
     int i2;
     int i3;
    } S;
```

I would define an enum representing the specific field:

```
typedef enum
{
  FIELD_ID_I1,
  FIELD_ID_I2,
  FIELD_ID_I3,

  FIELD_ID_MAX
} FieldId_e;
```

Then I would add a field parameter in your general function, managing internally the correct field to be returned. **Some smart error managing in case of wrong ID has to be done here. I just return -1 for brevity.**

```
int getField (S *s, FieldId id)
{
  int ret = -1; 

  switch(id)
  {
    case FIELD_ID_I1:
      ret = s->i1;
      break;

    case FIELD_ID_I2:
      ret = s->i2;
      break;

    case FIELD_ID_I3:
      ret = s->i3;
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Your doJob will become

```
void doJob (int (*get_field_func)(S *, FieldId), FieldId id){
 //some code
 S s;
 int v = get_field_func(&s, id);
 //some code 
}
```

And final call will become this one. But probably (and it depends on your scenario) having a single general function will make possible to omit the  function pointer, simplifying much the interface.

```
doJob(&getField, FIELD_ID_I1);
doJob(&getField, FIELD_ID_I2);
doJob(&getField, FIELD_ID_I3);
```

---

Just a short reference to another tricky solution that would require to play with pointers.

Do you know `offsetof` macro? [(Wikipedia EN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof)

> It evaluates to the offset (in bytes) of a given member within a
>   struct or union type, an expression of type size_t. The offsetof()
>   macro takes two parameters, the first being a structure name, and the
>   second being the name of a member within the structure.

In this case you could have something like

```
int getField (S *s, size_t offset);

doJob(&getField, offsetof(S, i1));
```